# Did the ripemd precompiled contract get deleted?

Tags: blockchain, accounts, out-of-gas, exceptions, precompiled-contracts

A bug "caused account 0000000000000000000000000000000000000003 to be deleted in block 2675119, even though the deletion should have been reverted due to an out of gas error."  [Source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/3341/files#r89548312)

1. Did account `0..3` get deleted?
2. Did it get restored (on the blockchain) by this [1 wei transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9edd044354bc72471d08ac240fda0f88a13db11ceef65c6e081a62747b8ed9f)?
3. Pre-[EIP161](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/161), would sending 0 wei to `0..3` been sufficient to restore `0..3` on the blockchain?  What would happen if 0 wei was sent?